# Google discovered pages from my sitemap, but none are indexed

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I've recently put a new site online. I've written content for it and created a sitemap. I submitted it to Google thinking that would be it, but it's been a couple of weeks and the site's pages still aren't indexed.

[image]

25 pages have been discovered, however none are indexed. Both links on the right are greyed out and not clickable.

[image]

Google Search Console tells me only 2 pages haven't been indexed because of issues, these two are:

- non-https version of my homepage
- non-www version of my homepage

The only indexed page is my homepage: https://www.example.com.

**What I've tried:**

- ✅ Checked the canonical tag is the same as the url
- ✅ Checked my robots.txt

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: / 

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

- ✅ Checked pages aren't too new. Some of them are more than a month old.
- ✅ Content is original. This was all written by hand.
- ✅ Site had issues or was offline. The site is hosted on Vercel and has been online constantly for a month.

I'm honestly really confused about what the issue could be.

[Site link](https://www.dinnerwithevie.com)
[Sitemap link](https://www.dinnerwithevie.com/sitemap.xml)
[Robots link](https://www.dinnerwithevie.com/robots.txt)

Comment: It usually takes a year for Google to trust a new site enough to index.  Pages that are a month old are rarely indexed on a new site.

Comment: Looks like you have a recipe site. Strongly suggest using schema ... looks like you made an attempt but the schema does not validate ... Note this is the one Google recommends https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dinnerwithevie.com%2Frecipes%2Feasy-quorn-chilli ... a free tool to generate recipe schema is available here https://digitalscholar.in/recipe-schema-generator-tool/ ... The general why a new site is not showing should answer the whys for all people in this boat ... specific to your case you could use Pinterest for parasite SEO or a YouTube channel.

Comment: When I say parasitic SEO, the SEOer are all abuze after the latest update that these social site are doing very well and their content does better on them than their own sites. Pinterest, loves to share recipes with each other. Comment on other recipes to get followers. create a pin to share yours. Google will notice the interest and come looking for your  content. But get the schema up first.

Comment: I must also point out that the parasitic SEO sites will likely rank below the original content in the next update, which historically would be between now and christmas.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions, will try it out. Every site I've made in the past was indexed very quickly, I had no idea any of this was required?